# Linearly Interpolate Missing Data in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands, linear-interpolation

COVID-19 Data obtained from [OurWorldInData](https://ourworldindata.org/covid-deaths) includes total_boosters column to track vaccine boosters in any given country. **My goal is** to create a column for daily new boosters (boosters_new), then create a 90 day rolling sum (boosters_90roll). **The problem is** total_boosters has a lot of missing data, so I would like to linearly interpolate the missing data. If the missing data is not filled in any way, then a rolling sum would be a poor estimate and would be visualized poorly.

I already have a working solution to this, but it is the trickiest query I've worked on. I am posting this question to learn if there are cleaner/more efficient ways of doing this.

**Sample input:**

| location | date | total_boosters |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Albania | 2022-03-07 | 245527 |
| Albania | 2022-03-08 |  |
| Albania | 2022-03-09 |  |
| Albania | 2022-03-10 | 248491 |
| Albania | 2022-03-11 |  |
| Albania | 2022-03-12 |  |
| Albania | 2022-03-13 |  |
| Albania | 2022-03-14 | 251024 |
| Albania | 2022-03-15 | 252161 |

**Sample output:**

| location | date | boosters_new | boosters_90roll |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Albania | 2022-03-07 | 988 | 988 |
| Albania | 2022-03-08 | 988 | 1,976 |
| Albania | 2022-03-09 | 988 | 2,964 |
| Albania | 2022-03-10 | 633.25 | 3,597.25 |
| Albania | 2022-03-11 | 633.25 | 4,230.5 |
| Albania | 2022-03-12 | 633.25 | 4,863.75 |
| Albania | 2022-03-13 | 633.25 | 5,497 |
| Albania | 2022-03-14 | 1,137 | 6,634 |
| Albania | 2022-03-15 | 886.8889 | 7,520.8889 |

**Current solution**

```sql
-- Group total_boosters and sequential nulls as boosters_group, then counts and numbers the rows in each group
WITH BoostersGrouped AS
(
SELECT
    location,
    date,
    total_boosters,
    boosters_group,
    COUNT(boosters_group) OVER (
        PARTITION BY location, boosters_group
    ) AS group_count,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY location, boosters_group
    ) AS group_nrow
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        location,
        date,
        total_boosters,
        COUNT(total_boosters) OVER (
            PARTITION BY location ORDER BY date
        ) AS boosters_group
    FROM Vaccinations
    ) grouped
),
-- Self join to get total_boosters for current and next booster_group
BoostersFilled AS
(
SELECT
    bg1.location,
    bg1.date,
    bg1.boosters_group,
    bg1.group_count,
    bg1.group_nrow,
    bg2.boosters_current,
    bg3.boosters_next
FROM BoostersGrouped bg1
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        location,
        boosters_group,
        max(total_boosters) AS boosters_current
    FROM BoostersGrouped
    GROUP BY location, boosters_group
    ) bg2
    ON bg1.location = bg2.location
    AND bg1.boosters_group = bg2.boosters_group
LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT
        location,
        boosters_group,
        max(total_boosters) AS boosters_next
    FROM BoostersGrouped
    GROUP BY location, boosters_group
    ) bg3
    ON bg1.location = bg3.location
    AND (bg1.boosters_group + 1) = bg3.boosters_group
),
-- Linearly interpolate total_boosters
BoostersInterp AS
(
SELECT
    location,
    date,
    CASE
        WHEN boosters_group = 0 THEN 0
        ELSE (boosters_current + ((boosters_next - boosters_current)* group_nrow / group_count))
    END AS boosters_interp
FROM BoostersFilled
),
-- Calculate daily boosters_new
BoostersNew AS
(
SELECT
    location,
    date,
    (boosters_interp - boosters_lag) AS boosters_new
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        location,
        date,
        boosters_interp,
        LAG(boosters_interp) OVER (
            PARTITION BY location ORDER BY date
        ) AS boosters_lag
    FROM BoostersInterp
    ) BoostersLag
)
-- Calculate 90 day rolling sum
SELECT
    location,
    date,
    boosters_new,
    SUM(boosters_new) OVER (
        PARTITION BY location ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 89 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS boosters_90roll
FROM BoostersNew;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting question!

I suspect that logic can be simplified (and possibly become more efficient?) by making more use of window functions.

Here is a query that does the linear regression directly on the `total_boosters` metric.

```
select location, date, 
    coalesce(
        total_boosters,
        total_boosters1 + (total_boosters2 - total_boosters1) * (rn - 1) / cnt
    ) total_boosters
from (
    select v.*, 
        min(total_boosters) over(partition by location, grp1) total_boosters1,
        min(total_boosters) over(partition by location, grp2) total_boosters2,
        count(*) over(partition by location, grp1) cnt,
        row_number() over(partition by location, grp1 order by date) rn 
    from (
        select v.*, 
            count(total_boosters) over(partition by location order by date) grp1,
            count(total_boosters) over(partition by location order by date desc) grp2
        from vaccinations v
    ) v
) v
```

The logic is to define groups of rows that either start (`grp1`) or end (`grp2`) with a non-null value, followed by null values ; using these groups, we can identify the "preceding" and "following" values, count the number of missing values and their positions : that's the second layer of the query. The most outer query does the linear regression.

Now it is quite easy to compute the `new_boosters` metrics, using `lag()`. Yur code already has a similar logic ; We can wrap the above query in a CTE, and then:

```
with cte as ( ... above query ...)
select location, date, total_boosters,
    total_boosters - lag_total_boosters as boosters_new,
    avg(total_boosters - lag_total_boosters) over(
        partition by location
        order by date rows between 89 preceding and current row
    ) boosters_90roll
from (
    select c.*, 
        lag(total_boosters) over(partition by location order by date) lag_total_boosters
    from cte c
) c
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TZJKWLWi)**:

| location | date | total_boosters | boosters_new | boosters_90roll |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Albania | 2022-03-07 | 245527.0000 | *null* | *null* |
| Albania | 2022-03-08 | 246515.0000 | 988.0000 | 988.0000 |
| Albania | 2022-03-09 | 247503.0000 | 988.0000 | 1976.0000 |
| Albania | 2022-03-10 | 248491.0000 | 988.0000 | 2964.0000 |
| Albania | 2022-03-11 | 249124.2500 | 633.2500 | 3597.2500 |
| Albania | 2022-03-12 | 249757.5000 | 633.2500 | 4230.5000 |
| Albania | 2022-03-13 | 250390.7500 | 633.2500 | 4863.7500 |
| Albania | 2022-03-14 | 251024.0000 | 633.2500 | 5497.0000 |
| Albania | 2022-03-15 | 252161.0000 | 1137.0000 | 6634.0000 |

Comment: This is an excellent response! This logic does much more condensed. One note is COALESCE() doesn't need total_boosters because the calculation 
total_boosters1 + (total_boosters2 - total_boosters1) * (rn - 1) / cnt) 
is equal to total_boosters anyway when total_boosters is not null. At which point COALESCE() is no longer needed. I also made some slight adjustments to get integers.